# What is the best way to stream 24/7 content from a server, which can be exported as an m3u file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, automation, video-streaming

I have 24 Lectures for my students, and I teach online to many people. I am trying to setup a server with IPTV software, so they can view the lectures going 24/7 and have VOD for other content related to the course.

How would I go about setting up an additional server to playback 24 hours of content on loop, and then export this via m3u to be used in the IPTV Panel. Or I should say how do I create the channel to begin with on the server side? Best OS?